# How to serialise a POJO with two different custom serialisers for two different apis in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsonserializer, java-custom-serialization

I am using Spring MVC for creating a restful API. I have two different API endpoints where I need to serialise same POJO in two different ways. I have illustrated the same below:

Course API

```
url - /course/{id}

response - {
    "id": "c1234",
    "name": "some-course",
    "institute": {
        "id": "i1234",
        "name": "XYZ College"
    }
}
```

My `Course` Pojo is in accordance with the above structure, so the default serialisation works.

```
class Course {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Institute institute;

    //getters and setters follow
}

class Institute {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    //getters and setters follow
}
```

Now, for another `Students` API

```
url - /student/{id}

response - {
    "id":"s1234",
    "name":"Jon Doe",
    "institute": {
        "id": "i1234",
        "name": "XYZ college"
    },
    "course": {
        "id": "c1234",
        "name": "some-course"
    }
}
```

And my `Student` class looks like this:

```
class Student {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Course course;

    //getters and setters follow
}
```

Please note that there is no `institute` property in `Student` class because institute can be transitively determined from the `course.getInstitute` getter. But that ends up in a serialisation structure similar to course API. How can I use a custom serialisation only for the Students API without modifying the POJO Structure.

There are a N number of solutions to this that come to my mind, which is the most elegant and preferred one, I would like to know.

Comment: First problem I see is that `course` shouldn't be a `String`. Accurate modeling might take care of the issue for you.

Comment: @chrylis Oh.. that was a typo, it is type of `Course` and not `String`. Have edited it.

Comment: Is this format a specific external requirement? It seems that it makes unnecessary assumptions and could be simplified by just making the REST API conform to the domain model.

Comment: It is intuitive for external world to say student studies in XYZ college than to say student studies in college where a certain course is running(uniquely). So the APIs are more on intuitive modeling.

Comment: Then perhaps what you ought to use is something like Jackson's ID serialization, where you can tell it to only serialize a particular object (the `Institute`) the first time and then refer to it by ID later.

Comment: If you are using Jackson you could ignore the properties that you don't want just adding this line `.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)` in your _ObjectMapper_

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the most elegant thing I sorted out which works for me.

So, here is my class `Student`

```
class Student {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"institute"})
    private Course course;

    //getters and setters

    //Adding one more getter
    public Institute getInstitute() {
        return this.course.getInstitute();
    }
}
```

This way I am exposing a Java bean property `institute` through a `getter` while not holding a reference to it in my `Student` Object.